# How to get a derivative with respect to scalar for $f(a)=y^T(aI+B)^{-1}y$?

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have an equation which I simplified to following form:
$$f(a)=y^T(aI+B)^{-1}y$$
where $a$ is scalar, $y$ is a column Nx1 vector, $I$ is an identity matrix of size NxN, and $B$ is any symmetric matrix of size NxN such that $aI+B$ is invertible.

I want to **find a gradient** with respect to $a$

Function $f(a)$ takes a scalar and returns a scalar, thus derivative with respect to $a$ should also return scalar. I wanted then apply chain rule by performing following decomposition:

$$g(A) = y^TA^{-1}y$$
$$h(a) = aI+B$$

hoping that:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial h}\frac{\partial h}{\partial a}$$
and then using known identity to deal with $y^TA^{-1}y$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial h}=-A^{-T}yy^TA^{-T}$$

But even without proceeding, with this being one of factors I wont get a scalar.

Potentially I am wrongly applying chain rule in this setting? Could you please explain how to fix my approach and calculate the gradient?

Comment: Your calculation of $\frac{\partial g}{\partial h}$ is perfectly fine, but the next step is a doozy. The term $\frac{\partial h}{\partial a}$ is the gradient of a matrix with respect to another matrix, i.e. a 4th order tensor. If you find some way to calculate it, then you must take the double-dot product of these two intermediate gradients. In matrix calculus, the chain rule is often difficult to apply for precisely this reason (of dealing with higher-order tensors).

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Sounds I should make friends with your solution which I just marked as accepted. Out of curiosity though - if I calculated that 4th order tensor, would the multiplication of both matrix and tensor-4 yield a scalar?

Comment: From brief look at multiplication rules of tensors I think it would yield a 8-th order tensor? Or perhaps one should pick different term than $\frac{\partial h}{\partial a}$ to make application of chain rule correct?

Comment: Sorry, I confused $a$ with $A$ in my initial comment. The term $\frac{\partial h}{\partial a}$ is the gradient of a matrix wrt a scalar, and is therefore a matrix. But you must use a double-dot product between the 2 matrix terms in the chain rule.

Comment: [The WIkipedia Matrix Calculus page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities) notes that “The chain rule ... unfortunately does not apply in matrix-by-scalar derivatives or scalar-by-matrix derivative.” There are some formulas there and in the Matrix Cookbook that are applicable to your problem, but I find it easiest to compute the differentials and go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the chain rule use differentials.
$$\eqalign{
A &= Ia+B \cr
dA&=I\,da \cr
dA^{-1} &= -A^{-1}\,dA\,A^{-1} = -A^{-2}\,da \cr
\cr
df
 &= y^T\,dA^{-1}\,y = -y^TA^{-2}y\,\,da \cr
\cr
\frac{df}{da} &= -y^TA^{-2}y \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I am not very familiar with differentials though, especially in matrix calculus, so I am not sure really why some of the transformations would hold. Is it possible to point out mistake in chain rule application, so I can come to similar solutions? Sorry, perhaps I should not have added 'simplest possible way'.

Comment: In particular I don't understand line $df=y^TdA^{-1}y$. I haven't seen identity $\frac{\partial af(X)b}{\partial X} = a\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial X}b$, unless it's some composite I am missing.

Comment: The product rule for differentials is quite general $$d(A\star B)=dA\star B+A\star dB$$ where $A,B$ can be scalars, vectors, matrices, or tensors, and $\star$ is any type of product that is valid between $A$ and $B$. That includes Hadamard, Frobenius, Kronecker, dyadic, tensor, or matrix products. There is no such rule for gradients, because taking the gradient changes the tensorial character, whereas differentials do not. If $v$ is a vector, then $dv$ is also a vector, but $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ is a matrix and this alters any product in which it appears.

Comment: Ah thanks for that! Silly of me not to think this may still be applicable!